# How to "re-activate" a link once the user scrolls away from an anchor section?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm using Vue.js `2.3.3` with vue-router `2.5.3`. I created a `Navbar` component that has bookmarks (or links) pointing to specific sections on the landing page, like so:

```
<router-link to="/#our-services" class="nav-item item is-tab">
    Our Services <!-- Jumps to #our-services on the home page -->
</router-link>
```

I defined my router in the following way:

```
export default new VueRouter({
    routes, // routes are defined in a var above...
    mode: 'history',
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
        if (to.hash) {
            return { selector: to.hash }
        } else {
            return { x: 0, y: 0 }
        }
    },
    linkActiveClass: 'is-active'
})
```

Now, this does seem work; if I click on "Our Services" link in the navbar, it jumps to `#our-services`. **However**:

1. If I scroll away from `#our-services` `div` element, and click on "Our Services" link again, it doesn't bring me back to the `div`; clicking on the link does not produce anything;
2. Moreover, the `<a>` element of the `router-link` retains the `is-active` class even though you scrolled away from the section; it would be nice to keep track of where you are on the page and adjust the `is-active` class on the link appropriately.

Any suggestions on how to solve these two problems? Should I listen to the scroll event in the second case? Thanks!

Comment: You need an event handler on scroll that does `window.location.hash = ''`

Comment: @RoyJ How can I do this only when `window.scrollY` goes above or below the anchored `div` element (i.e. when the user "leaves" the section)?

Comment: For the element, `el.getBoundingClientRect()`, and compare its top to `window.pageYOffset`

Comment: Ok I couldn't figure this out. `getBoundingClientRect()` called on either `e.target` or `e.srcElement` fails with a `not a function` error. Can you post a more elaborate answer? I would accept it. Also, should I assign the listener to all `div`s on the page or just to the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever your scrolling object is (likely `window`), you should add an event listener to handle scroll events:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler, false);
```

Your `scrollhandler` function should check whether there is a hash on the current window location, and if so, check whether the associated element is out of range, and if so, clear the hash.

I can't use the real location hash or window in a snippet, but this is kind of what you would want to do.

```js
let hash = '#second';
const scrollingEl = document.querySelector('.scrollingArea');

function handleScrollEvent() {
  if (hash) {
    const winY = scrollingEl.scrollTop;
    const hashElY = document.querySelector(hash).getBoundingClientRect().top;
    
    if (hashElY < 0 || hashElY > winY + scrollingEl.height) {
      hash = '';
    }
    console.log(winY, hashElY);
  }
}

scrollingEl.addEventListener('scroll', handleScrollEvent, false);
```

```css
.scrollingArea {
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.scrollingArea>div {
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollingArea">
  <div id="first">First</div>
  <div id="second">Second</div>
  <div id="third">Third</div>
  <div id="fourth">Fourth</div>
</div>
```